# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException-ORA-01722: invalid number - Prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, placeholder

I am fixing some SQL Injection issues in the code by removing the replaceAll() in code. I am replacing the named parameters in the query with the placeholders and using in it the prepared statement. I am getting below issue, please advice.

Query:

```
<entry key= "GET DATA">
select ATYPE, ANAME, AGRID, AVALUE
from ALG_RSV.TERMS
--where AGRID in (':AGRS')  // changed this line
where AGRID in (?) // to this 
order by 2,1
```

Code:

```
 {...
    List<String> agreeIDs = getAgree
    String agrID = String.join(",",agreeIDs);
    // String sqlQuery = CSRConsole.getProperty(GET DATA).replaceAll(":AGRS", agrID);// 
    commented out replaceALL 

    String sqlQuery = CSRConsole.getProperty(GET DATA); //Changed like this
    prepStat= Conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
    prepStat.setString(1, agrID);// changed like this, getting issue in this line
    rs = prepStat.executeQuery();
    .....}
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException-ORA-01722: invalid  number

Can someone help me with this? what is the issue here? how to convert named parameters to placeholders?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the entirety of your question, but the Java `PreparedStatement` statement API does not used named placeholders, it only uses positional placeholders which are indicated by `?`.  From the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), here is a sample code:

```java
String updateString = "update COFFEES " + "set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
PreparedStatement updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
updateSales.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: yes.. that's, why I am changing named parameters to, use positional placeholders ?, and using in it the preparedStatement. Now I am getting this issue

Comment: _Edit_ your question and show data for the full workflow you have.  It is not clear (to me) what you are trying to do here.